# Programmatically open content in IE 10 desktop mode from Windows 8 mode

Tags: javascript, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

If I have content running in IE 10 in Windows 8 mode, is it possible to programmatically open that content, or other content, in IE 10 in desktop mode? And/or vice versa?

Comment: are you asking how to do it programmatically or are you asking can you switch an app designed for windows 8 full screen to be used in a "windowed" mode or environment?

Comment: Programmatically. E.g., click a link in IE 10 Windows 8 mode, JavaScript responds by opening IE 10 in desktop mode.

Comment: Have looked at the windows 8 sdk for js or is that not what you're after.

Comment: Does the Windows 8 SDK for JavaScript work inside web pages running in IE 10?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, but there is a way to open a popup with a link to open your site in the desktop version of IE10. You can do this by including the following meta element:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="requiresActiveX=true" />
```

Or the HTTP header:

```
X-UA-Compatible: requiresActiveX=true
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj193557(v=vs.85).aspx for more info.